# Saving an Excel 2016 document without changing its content changes its hash

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

As the title suggests, the hash (crc-32, md5, sha-1, etc) always changes when saving an excel 2016 file (.xlsx) without having changed any of the contents.

This is detrimental to any document version system.

Anyone knows how to remedy this? Setting the file to Read-only solves it but it’s not very practical.

Comment: Perhaps the hash includes the date/time the document was saved?

Comment: Most likely. Some metadata gets added to the byte stream. But how to disable this from an Excel point of view would be nice... Word does not have any problems with this.